# Convert time between UTC and specific timezone - New Internationalization API

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

I am trying to use new [Internationalization API](http://generatedcontent.org/post/59403168016/esintlapi) .I use chrome
Version 31.0.1623.0 canary

What I want is

1. Convert Date Time between UTC and specific time zone (`America/New_York` in the example)
2. To check whether the conversion is Daylight Savings changes aware.

So, is it possible with the current level of support to convert between these two timezone, when

a. Daylight savings is active

```
//EDT: 11/2/2013 01:04:05
//UTC: 11/2/2013 05:04:05
```

b. Not active

```
//EST: 11/3/2013 01:04:05
//UTC: 11/3/2013 06:04:05
```

Also why is it December, when I specify month 11 in the below example.

http://jsfiddle.net/kr8FW/2/

```
console.clear();

var dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'});

//EDT: 11/2/2013 01:04:05
//UTC: 11/2/2013 05:04:05

var utc1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 11, 2, 5, 4, 5))
console.log(dtf.format(utc1));
console.log(utc1.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}));

//EST: 11/3/2013 01:04:05
//UTC: 11/3/2013 06:04:05

var utc2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 11, 3, 5, 4, 5))
console.log(utc2.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}));
```

The output was

```
Console was cleared (index):21
12/2/2013 (index):29
12/2/2013 12:04:05 AM (index):30
12/3/2013 12:04:05 AM
```

Comment: December: month start from 0

Comment: Also, your example cases are correct, but you didn't use the second one.  You passed 5:04:05, not 06:04:05.

Comment: thanks Matt. Also, missed that JS time starts at 0. Will work on the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript Date says the months are 0-11.

Daylight savings ends at 2 AM on 3 Nov 2013. So both times are within daylight savings in US Eastern time zone.